# Using apply function on a list to get plots

Tags: r, loops

I can get the plot on one dataset but have trouble with lapply. Here is my code:first get stats then plot the stats.

```
stats1<- data %>%
  group_by(Group,ERF) %>%
  summarize(mean=mean (Latency),
            sd = sd(Latency),
            sem = sd(Latency)/sqrt(n()),
            n = n())
ggplot(stats1,aes(x=ERF,y=mean,fill=Group))+ geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sem, ymax = mean + sem),                            
                width = 0.2)
```

The above code works. Below is the code using lapply with splitlist

```
splitlist=split(data,data$Group)
stats<-lapply(splitlist,function(x){mean=mean(x$Latency)
                             sd = sd(x$Latency)
                             sem = sd(x$Latency)/sqrt(length(x$Latency))
                             })
lapply(splitlist,function(x) ggplot(data=x,aes(ERF,mean,fill=Group))+ geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
        geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sem, ymax = mean + sem),                            
                      width = 0.2)
```

The stats only returns mean but not sem; then here is the error with the ggplot
*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = mean.
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?*

How can I fix the error and get the plots from each data list? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) would have been helpful.

You should calculate the stats and plot in the same `lapply` code, however you don't need to recalculate the stats since you already have it in `stats1`. `split` `stats1` based on `Group` and use that data to plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

splitlist = split(stats1,stats1$Group)

lapply(splitlist,function(x) {
  ggplot(data=x, aes(ERF,mean)) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sem, ymax = mean + sem), width = 0.2)
}) -> list_plots

list_plots
```

Comment: So elegant. Split stats, that's it!